# Can't boot into windows 10 bootable flashdrive

Tags: windows, grub

I can boot into a manjaro linux bootable usb but not a windows 10 bootable usb.

grub rescue mode launches everytime.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Is the boot order set appropriately?

Comment: Does the computer have UEFI BIOS?

Comment: Can you sure that the USB is bootable? Please make sure the USB is bootable first. Secondly, set the usb on the top in boot order.   If these still doesn;t work, you may need to configure UEFI in your device.

Comment: yes, yes and yes. Don't worry about responding, i got it working already

Answer (score 0):

I finally managed to get it working, for some reason the grub boot menu was on the usb, i tried formatting it with windows on my other computer but it didn't work.

Then formatted it with Gparted on manjaro linux and it finally worked after that.

Comment: Just to be clear for others, if you get an error, wipe the usb 100%, _then_ try booting windows 10 from it